# Python: How to select all values below a certain limit in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, limit

I have this graph, I need to find how long the dip lasts (in terms of the x axis). I figured if I could just take all the points below a certain value (about 0.9996) and then find the max and min  x values within that range I could figure it out that way?
I just don't know how to do it!

[image: plot of a lightcurve]

Comment: Is this data stored in a DataFrame? We would need to see the raw data in order to answer your question. Generally showing your code and/or a sample of your data set is helpful to ensure your question is reproducible

Comment: It's better if you post the code you use to load the data from the file. That way, we can see what the data type is.

Comment: It's easier to help when you provide a [mcve]. You might find the [ruptures](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures/) package useful for detecting change points in your data.

Comment: Don't you normally fit this kind of data with a proper model for your transiting source, that has all the necessary parameters? That would be the proper way to do it.